# What account does the Azure App Service Web Worker use? (O365 integration)

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We have created our first Azure App Service for a simple single page web application (.Net). Now the app has to send email using our O365 account. We don't want to hardcode a user name and password inside the app. My first thought (thinking like it's on-prem) is to figure out the service account under which the Web Worker is executing then grant access for that account to send email. Is that account published somewhere on the Azure Portal? is that the best approach? is it doable? if not, I'll need to do more research on how to store Web application settings in an Azure database and proceed to create a service account / password in there to retrieve and use at runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Microsoft Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview

You can create an app in Azure AD and give it permissions to send email. Here is a sample that can send email via the Graph API: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-connect-sample

Comment: Thank you. We'll explore it. It seems like an overkill but it'll allow us to learn something new.

Comment: After a lot of reading, we ended up using the "standard code snippet" you would find anywhere to send an email using the O365 SMTP. We "hardcoded" an O365 user name and password. The only trick was to make sure that the account being used doesn't have SSO enabled. It had to be a <xxx>.onmicrosoft.com and voila!